# Swipe to the closest element on scrollable list

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I use FlatList for horizontal scroll. It works as expected. I can scroll to next item or scroll to last item quickly. But i need to do scroll only to next item. So every swipe should scroll me to the closest item. Can i do it using FlatList?

Answer (score 0):

Found that FlatList has disableIntervalMomentum prop. It resolved my issue